# Calling python and C++ scripts within a lua script

Tags: python, c++, lua

I am trying to create a program that will process a lot of images. For the image processing I am currently using a python script which utilises openCV library.

So, this is my problem:

I am parsing some data inside main.lua
After the data is parsed I would like to send it to processing.py which will return the control back to main.lua upon finishing the process and return the result of the images it processed. Then the main.lua will display the images using Love2D engine and continue the program.

How do I call python interpreter inside lua interpreter?

I need something like this to occur:

```
result_of_python := call processing.py with arg: image_data
```

Additionally, how would I call C++ code (should I call source or compiled code?) inside lua script as I would like to improve overall performance with C++ openCV instead of python openCV.

Comment: You can run `python` and receive text sent by `processing.py` to stdout: `local pipe=io.popen('python processing.py data'); local result = pipe:read'*a'; pipe:close(); do_something_with(result)`

Comment: The thing is I do not wish to send "text" data. As I mentioned I am manipulating with images, hence, I need to send a variable which is table containing read image data (numbers)

Comment: Maybe you can send the data to your Python script on its `stdin` rather than as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! That certainly works! The problem was that the Egor's code is incomplete. I've found the way to send the data. It is similar, but different from the code.